# Map to object with an accumulator

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a more idiomatic way to `mapToObject` in lodash?

```
var accumulator = {};
_.map([1, 2, 3], function (number) {
    accumulator[number] = number + 1;
});

// {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

Is there a way to do this without explicitly providing an accumulator for the map function?

```
_.mapToObject([1, 2, 3], function (accumulator, number) { 
    return accumulator[number] = number + 1;
}
```

Comment: First, why are you using `map` when treating it as a simple looper? Second, I don't know if underscore has it, but `Array.prototype.reduce` is what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `.reduce()` is for:

```
var accumulator = 
  _.reduce([1, 2, 3], function(acc, num) { acc[num] = num + 1; return acc; }, {});
```

In modern browsers there's a native `.reduce()` on the Array prototype that's more-or-less the same as the versions provided by lodash and Underscore.

The `.map()` API is for creating a new array from an existing array. If you just want to do something with each element of an array, you'd use `.forEach()`. The `.filter()` API is for making an array of selected elements of an array.

Comment: A point that deserves mention, imho.  The  extra "{}" parameter passed to the `reduce` function "... return acc; }, {});" sets the initial value  for the accumulator.  if not provided accumulation proceeds with element #1 combined with element #0. When provided, accumulation proceeds with element #0 combined with the provided initial value. Thus, without it, the correct example @pointy provides  would use the first value "1" and fail with : TypeError: Cannot create property '2' on number '1'.